# Mount Error for Block Storage on Azure kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, mount, azure-files

I have been trying to mount a file share on Kubernetes pod hosted on AKS in Azure. So far, I have tried to:
 1. Successfully created a secret by base64 encoding the name and the key
 2. Create a yaml by specifying the correct configurations
 3. Once I apply it using `kubectl apply -f azure-file-pod.yaml`, it gives me the following error:

> Output: mount error: could not resolve address for
>   demo.file.core.windows.net: Unknown error

I have an Azure File Share by the name of `demo`.

Here is my yaml file:
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: azure-files-pod
spec:
 containers:
  - image: microsoft/sample-aks-helloworld
    name: azure
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
 volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: demo
      readOnly: false`

How can this possibly be resolved?

Comment: You should check your Azure File Share if the account name and account key is right.

Comment: It seems to be correct

Comment: As the error said, the address "demo.file.core.windows.net" is unknown. And the address used to be `https://storageaccountName.file.core.windows.net/`. So you should check all the commands and parameters.